# Tap on WKWebview content using ui tests

Tags: swift, wkwebview, xcode-ui-testing

I wanted to tap on webview. No specific content. But any where in a webivew.

The webview content is having a graph. I need to tap on the graph.
How can I do that?

I tried using this:

```
XCUIApplication().descendants(matching: .webView).element.tap()
```

But no luck

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
func testSomething() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()
    app.webviews.tap()
}
```